# how to redirect to a html page in local computer

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, web, redirect

i have created a html page with 2 text fields and 1 button(call it A.html) and the file is  is in my local computer. I have added host entry to access the file via localhost.

when i click on to the button(in A.html)it redirect to another corporate login page where i have to enter valid email id and password, if that is successful then i want the page to redirect back to A.html page which is in my local. since its not https it shows page cannot be displayed.

can you please help us with the solution for this.

Comment: Your website(A.html) should be hosted and exposed on internet so other website can talk/redirect to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place that inside your localmachine's webserver - means create localhost website on your machine's  webserver and bind a self signed SSL cert, so that you can have HTTPS working on your machine.

Here is an example to do it on IIS - https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.

If your machine is windows machine - Try enabling WebServer - Server feature so that you can have IIS(Webserver) locally